How to hide the interface on a screen recording
I tried to make such an interface using a transparent window tracking clicks and drawings using ScreenDC. but when you refresh the window in the drawing part it starts showing up on the screen recording
I don't have the code, I accidentally erased it. I expected that the interface would not appear on the screen recording.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
